# Bucket URL access denied

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created my first bucket, and when trying to access it by typing storage.googleapis.com/mybucket, I get the following in my browser. I am totally ignorant in respect to all things code, and only would like to be able to solve this issue in order to be able to use a WordPress plugin, WP2Cloud, which integrates Google Cloud Storage with WordPress. Here's what's in my browser:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
</Error
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want your bucket to be publicly readable?

Comment: For those who wish to make their bucket publicly readable, check out [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** use storage.googleapis.com/mybucket or mybucket.storage.googleapis.com directly from browser. You need to pass GoogleAccessId,Expires, Signature.

If you want to use from browser you need to use Signed URLs

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

example of Signed-URLs:

http://mybucket.storage.googleapis.com/testdata.txt?**GoogleAccessId**=1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com&**Expires**=1331155464&**Signature**=BClz9e4UA2MRRDX62TPd8sNpUCxVsqUDG3YGPWvPcwN%2BmWBPqwgUYcOSszCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw%3D

Comment: And alternatively you can view your bucket data at https://storage.cloud.google.com/mybucket